# Generate “hash” functions programmatically

Tags: algorithm, hash

I have some extremely old legacy procedural code which takes 10 or so enumerated inputs [ i0, i1, i2, ... i9 ] and generates 170 odd enumerated outputs [ r0, r1, ... r168, r169 ]. By enumerated, I mean that each individual input & output has its own set of distinct value sets e.g. [ red, green, yellow ] or [ yes, no ] etc.

I’m putting together the entire state table using the existing code, and instead of puzzling through them by hand, I was wondering if there was an algorithmic way of determining an appropriate function to get to each result from the 10 inputs. Note, not all input columns may be required to determine an individual output column, i.e. r124 might only be dependent on i5, i6 and i9.

These are not continuous functions, and I expect I might end up with some sort of hashing function approach, but I wondered if anyone knew of a more repeatable process I should be using instead? (If only there was some Karnaugh map like approach for multiple value non-binary functions ;-) )

Comment: How many combinations of enumerated inputs can you have?  That is, do you need automated reasoning to process the existing code, or is it a question of trying to simplify a known set of "this input creates that output" to a smallish set of rules for the same?

Comment: Good question. For a couple of them the enumerated values are approx 80, the rest are are 20 or less. So quite a large set, at least for me.

Comment: Plus... even some way of determining irrelevant inputs for a result column would be useful. The legacy code is extremely arcane - dynamic coding using multiple loops with the counter decrementing as well as incrementing - reminds one of the “Programmer called Mel” from the jargon file ;-)

Comment: If thedomains are small, you could use the product-of-primes approach.

Comment: Why we can't just generate all the combinations and then for each output figure out which inputs matter using the simplest schema - if for all values of given input no output change across all combinations, then it does not matter (for given output). BTW if you can post a code sample, it would help to make sure that we understand right.

Comment: Eugene, I’m preparing to do that, but given the size of the matrix 10 x 170 I thought I’d ask if there was a programmatic approach. Shoot me for being lazy ! ;-)

Comment: Also, assume value choices are for sake of argument 80,80,10,15,2,3,5,2,2,20 .... that’s a lot of rows to wade through... 80x80x10x15x2 3x5x2x2x20

Comment: Can you please show an actual sample from the original procedural code? Perhaps we could parse it? (Might not be worth the effort...)

Comment: Perfect hashing (googlable) may fit the bill, depending on what you mean by "appropriate function".  Specifically an order-preserving minimal perfect hash

Comment: It’s a FileMaker solution, so there’s procedural code, functional calculations, and field definitions... which makes pulling the code for even one column extremely difficult. It’s a rats nest of a black box :-(

Comment: Matt - this also looks promising. I will investigate. Thanks!

Comment: I actually not suggesting to manually do that -- I'm talking about generating of "Karnaugh map" as you put it automatically for all the combinations, and then get rid of input variables which does not affect the output, should be pretty straightforward...

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to actually enumerate all possible input/output sequences, here is a theoretical approach to tackle this that should be fairly effective.

First, consider the [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) of the output.  Suppose that you have `n` possible input sequences, and `x[i]` is the number of ways to get `i` as an output.  Let `p[i] = float(x[i])/float(n[i])` and then the entropy is `- sum(p[i] * log(p[i]) for i in outputs)`.  (Note, since `p[i] < 1` the `log(p[i])` is a negative number, and therefore the entropy is positive.  Also note, if `p[i] = 0` then we assume that `p[i] * log(p[i])`  is also zero.)

The amount of entropy can be thought of as the amount of information needed to predict the outcome.

Now here is the key question.  What variable gives us the most information about the output per information about the input?

If a particular variable `v` has `in[v]` possible values, the amount of information in specifying `v` is `log(float(in[v]))`.  I already described how to calculate the entropy of the entire set of outputs.  For each possible value of `v` we can calculate the entropy of the entire set of outputs for that value of `v`.  The amount of information given by knowing `v` is the entropy of the total set minus the *average* of the entropies for the individual values of `v`.

Pick the variable `v` which gives you the best ratio of `information_gained_from_v/information_to_specify_v`.  Your algorithm will start with a switch on the set of values of that variable.

Then for each value, you repeat this process to get cascading nested if conditions.

This will generally lead to a fairly compact set of cascading nested if conditions that will focus on the input variables that tell you as much as possible, as quickly as possible, with as few branches as you can manage.

---

Now this assumed that you had a comprehensive enumeration.  But what if you don't?

The answer to that is that the analysis that I described can be done for a random sample of your possible set of inputs.  So if you run your code with, say, 10,000 random inputs, then you'll come up with fairly good entropies for your first level.  Repeat with 10,000 each of your branches on your second level, and the same will happen.  Continue as long as it is computationally feasible.

If there are good patterns to find, you will quickly find a lot of patterns of the form, "If you put in this that and the other, here is the output you always get."  If there is a reasonably short set of nested ifs that give the right output, you're probably going to find it.  After that, you have the question of deciding whether to actually verify by hand that each bucket is reliable, or to trust that if you couldn't find any exceptions with 10,000 random inputs, then there are none to be found.

---

Tricky approach for the validation.  If you can find fuzzing software written for your language, run the fuzzing software with the goal of trying to tease out every possible internal execution path for each bucket you find.  If the fuzzing software decides that you can't get different answers than the one you think is best from the above approach, then you can probably trust it.

Comment: This looks promising - I will investigate!

Comment: I think the is deterministic solution, will try to add my code demonstrating it later today.

Comment: @EugeneD.Gubenkov The "for the sake of argument" estimate of how many possible input combinations there were went over 2 billion.  Data structures starting with input data in that size range often runs into computational constraints...

Comment: @btilly, according to the problem statement there are only 10 inputs each of which has only several values - this can obviously be calculated fully

Comment: @EugeneD.Gubenkov In the comments we are told to assume that the number of values per input is 80, 80, 10, 15, 2, 3, 5, 2, 2, and 20.  The total number of combinations is the product of those counts, which is 2,304,000,000.  Depending on the actual numbers, the number of combinations could easily be an order of magnitude larger or smaller than this.

Comment: Depending on resources, how fast the function is, and so on, we could be on either side of feasible for actually enumerating all input/output combinations.  And on the wrong side of feasible for simply manipulating it all in memory.  Which is why I focused on an approach that can start making progress from a random subsample of feasible size.  And hopefully can quickly discover some branches that avoid having to enumerate large chunks of the overall search space.

Comment: @btilly, that makes perfect sense -- did not see this comment about input sizes... good answer!

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm is pretty straightforward. Given possible values for each input we can generate all the input vectors possible. Then per each output we can just eliminate these inputs that do no matter for the output. As the result we for each output we can get a matrix showing output values for all the input combinations excluding the inputs that do not matter for given output.

Sample input format (for code snipped below):

```cs
var schema = new ConvertionSchema()
{
    InputPossibleValues = new object[][]
    {
        new object[] { 1, 2, 3, }, // input #0
        new object[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' }, // input #1
        new object[] { "foo", "bar" }, // input #2
    },
    Converters = new System.Func<object[], object>[]
    {
        input => input[0], // output #0
        input => (int)input[0] + (int)(char)input[1], // output #1
        input => (string)input[2] == "foo" ? 1 : 42, // output #2
        input => input[2].ToString() + input[1].ToString(), // output #3
        input => (int)input[0] % 2, // output #4
    }
};
```

Sample output:

[image: sample out]

Leaving the heart of the backward conversion below. Full code in a form of Linqpad snippet is there: http://share.linqpad.net/cknrte.linq.

```cs
public void Reverse(ConvertionSchema schema)
{
    // generate all possible input vectors and record the resul for each case
    // then for each output we could figure out which inputs matters

    object[][] inputs = schema.GenerateInputVectors();

    // reversal path
    for (int outputIdx = 0; outputIdx < schema.OutputsCount; outputIdx++)
    {
        List<int> inputsThatDoNotMatter = new List<int>();

        for (int inputIdx = 0; inputIdx < schema.InputsCount; inputIdx++)
        {
            // find all groups for input vectors where all other inputs (excluding current) are the same
            // if across these groups outputs are exactly the same, then it means that current input
            // does not matter for given output

            bool inputMatters = inputs.GroupBy(input => ExcudeByIndexes(input, new[] { inputIdx }), input => schema.Convert(input)[outputIdx], ObjectsByValuesComparer.Instance)
                .Where(x => x.Distinct().Count() > 1)
                .Any();

            if (!inputMatters)
            {
                inputsThatDoNotMatter.Add(inputIdx);
                Util.Metatext($"Input #{inputIdx} does not matter for output #{outputIdx}").Dump();
            }
        }

        // mapping table (only inputs that matters)
        var mapping = new List<dynamic>();

        foreach (var inputGroup in inputs.GroupBy(input => ExcudeByIndexes(input, inputsThatDoNotMatter), ObjectsByValuesComparer.Instance))
        {
            dynamic record = new ExpandoObject();

            object[] sampleInput = inputGroup.First();

            object output = schema.Convert(sampleInput)[outputIdx];

            for (int inputIdx = 0; inputIdx < schema.InputsCount; inputIdx++)
            {
                if (inputsThatDoNotMatter.Contains(inputIdx))
                    continue;

                AddProperty(record, $"Input #{inputIdx}", sampleInput[inputIdx]);

            }

            AddProperty(record, $"Output #{outputIdx}", output);

            mapping.Add(record);
        }

        // input x, ..., input y, output z form is needed
        mapping.Dump();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dycey, I hope that's what you meant by "Karnaugh map like approach for multiple value non-binary functions"